# $X_n+\tau Y\to_D X+\tau Y$ for every fixed positive constant $\tau$ implies $X_n \to_D X$.

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $X, Y, X_n's$ be random variables for which $X_n+\tau Y\to_D X+\tau Y$ for every fixed positive constant $\tau$. Show that $X_n \to_D X$.

I dont think we can let $\tau\to0$ and claim the result. Any hint on this question?

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$\Bbb E[e^{itX_n}] - \Bbb E[e^{itX}] =   \bigg(\Bbb E[e^{it X_{n}}] - \Bbb E[e^{it X_{n} + i t \epsilon Y}]\bigg) + \bigg(\Bbb E[e^{it X_{n} + i t \epsilon Y}] - \Bbb E[e^{it X + i t \epsilon Y}]\bigg)+ \bigg(\Bbb E[e^{it X + i t \epsilon Y}]-\Bbb E[e^{it X}]\bigg).$$
Now let $n \to \infty$ in the right hand side. By the assumption of the problem statement, the middle term goes to zero. Note that $|e^{itX_n + i t\epsilon Y} - e^{i t X_n} | = |e^{i t\epsilon Y}-1| \leq \min\{2,t\epsilon|Y|\},$ and the same bound remains true if we replace $X_n$ by $X$. Thus the first and third terms are bounded in absolute value by $\Bbb E[\min\{2,\epsilon t |Y|\}]$. Hence we showed that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \big|\Bbb E[e^{i t X_n}] - \Bbb E[e^{it X}]\big| \leq 2 \Bbb E[ \min \{2,\epsilon t |Y|\}].$$
Here $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and it only appears on the right hand side, so we can let it tend to zero, and by DCT the right side converges to zero while the left side remains unchanged.

Comment: I doubt about the convergence of the first and third terms on the right. For the first term, the first expectation is taken over the marginal of $X_n$ but the second over the joint of $(X_n, Y_n)$. Hence, I argue that $$P( d (e^{i t X_n}, e^{i t X_n+i t \epsilon Y})<\epsilon') \neq P(e^{it \epsilon Y}< \epsilon')$$

Comment: @JonMcDonald: I made a comment to address your concern. I pasted it as an answer as it was a little too long for the comment section. I hope that convinces you that Shalop's arguments are all valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to complement the answer by Shalop and  to address a comment posted by the OP.

The first and third are bounded by a small term:
$$
\begin{align}
\Big|\Bbb E[e^{it X_{n}}]-\Bbb E[e^{it X_{n} + i t \epsilon Y}]\Big|&\leq \Bbb E\big[\big|e^{itX_n}\big(1-e^{it\varepsilon Y}\big)\big|\big]\leq\mathbb{E}\big[|1-e^{it\varepsilon Y}|\big]\leq \Bbb E[\min(2,\varepsilon t|Y|)]\\
\Big|\Bbb E[e^{it X}]-\Bbb E[e^{it X + i t \epsilon Y}]\Big|&\leq \Bbb E\big[\big|e^{itX}\big(1-e^{it\varepsilon Y}\big)\big|\big]\leq\mathbb{E}\big[|1-e^{it\varepsilon Y}|\big]\leq \Bbb E[\min(2,\varepsilon t|Y|)]
\end{align}
$$

Here, we use the fact that for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
\Big|e^{ix}-\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}\Big|\leq \min\Big(
\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},\frac{2|x|^n}{n!}\Big)\\
$$

Dominated convergence implies that $\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\Bbb E[\min(2,\varepsilon t|Y|)]=0$

Comment: Thanks. In retrospect I should have just kept it as $\Bbb E|1-e^{i t \epsilon Y}|]$ and then directly applied DCT as $\epsilon \to 0$. For some reason I made it more confusing by writing the extra bound.

Comment: @Shalop: YEs, the last bound is not needed and one can get the result directly from $E|1-e^{it\varepsilon Y}|$ though dominated convergence. In any case, I think the OPs confession of a different nature.